Error sending form data with json and file from react to spring boot
we are developing a microservice application with react.js MFE and spring boot microservices
I have a react form with several fields to fullfill and 6 files to upload, and i'm posting it to a spring boot rest controller.
this is react submit function we are using to submit the form
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setErrorMessage(null);
    setErrorMessageForiEMessaggi(null);

    if (selectedFori.length == 0 || selectedMaterie.length == 0) {
      setErrorMessageForiEMessaggi(
        "Bisogna selezionare almeno un foro e una materia"
      );
    } else {
      const data = new FormData();

      //aggiungo i valori delle select
      const formDataAggiornato = {
        ...formData,
        ordine: selectedOrdine,
        regioneSedeStudio: selectedRegioneSedeStudio,
        provinciaSedeStudio: selectedProvinciaSedeStudio,
        comuneSedeStudio: selectedComuneSedeStudio,
        materia1: selectedMaterie.length >= 1 ? selectedMaterie[0] : null,
        materia2: selectedMaterie.length >= 2 ? selectedMaterie[1] : null,
        materia3: selectedMaterie.length == 3 ? selectedMaterie[2] : null,
        foro1: selectedFori.length >= 1 ? selectedFori[0] : null,
        foro2: selectedFori.length >= 2 ? selectedFori[1] : null,
        foro3: selectedFori.length == 3 ? selectedFori[2] : null,
      };

      for (const [key, file] of Object.entries(prevFiles)) {
        if (file) {
          const newFileName = file?.name
            ? `${key}_${file.name}`
            : `${key}_${file}`;
          console.log("nome file", newFileName);
          const renamedFile = new File([file], newFileName, {
            type: file.type,
          });
          data.append(`files`, renamedFile);
        }
      }

      data.append("avvocato", JSON.stringify(formDataAggiornato));

      const requestOptions = {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      };

      // Effettua la richiesta POST utilizzando fetch
      fetch(url + API_PATH, requestOptions).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          console.log(response);

          //chiudo modale
          toggleModal(!isOpen);

          //svuoto domanda
          setDomanda(null);

          //ricarico lista domande
          reloadListaDomande();

          //stampo messaggio successo in TableDomanda
          setSuccessMessageTable(
            domanda?.id
              ? "Modifica avvenuta con successo!"
              : "Elemento creato correttamente"
          );

          setErrorMessage(null);
          setErrorMessageForiEMessaggi(null);

          return response.json();
        } else {
          setErrorMessage(
            "Errore durante il salvataggio dei dati, ricaricare la pagina"
          );
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    }
  };

and this is the rest controller to save data and files
  @Operation(summary = "salva l'avvocato", tags = {"Avvocati"})
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('userfo')")
    @PostMapping(value = "", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201")
    public ResponseEntity<AvvocatoDto> salvaAvvocato(@RequestPart("avvocato") @Valid AvvocatoDto dto, @RequestPart(value = "files", required = false) List<MultipartFile> files) throws IOException, ForbiddenOpException {

when form is submitted the following error is returned
2024-07-15 13:06:33.692 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] c.c.a.exception.ExceptionsHandler        : GENERIC ERROR : Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:211) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:140) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179) ~[spring-web-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146) ~[spring-web-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]

if I execute the same post with the same data (json+files) via Postman it works perfectly
Where am I doing wrong?

could you share the request curl?

How was they work?
First of all, on client side when you post form data with files fetch will set Content-Type like multipart/form-data; boundary=----....
On spring side, your request will be resolved by method resolveArgument in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver and it cannot convert text to AvvocatoDto at the first parameter.
In deep
The resolver received null when it try to get content type of the first parameter and set to "application/octet-stream" (which you see on error log) after that there is no converter which can convert from application/octet-stream to AvvocatoDto class. See more details in AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver#readWithMessageConverters
How to deal with?
Solution 1
You are able to create model class to hold all fields and files, please refer to this post
Solution 2
Change the first parameter as String
@RequestPart("avvocato") String avvocatoStr

and deserialize and valid it manually.
Hope help.

i think it is not necessary to specify the content type because it is set by the browser, furthermore if I execute the same post with the same data (json+files) via Postman it works perfectly ... (updated my post)
